# Geometry - circles

Tags: geometry

[image]

2 equal circles , each of radius 10cm , have Centres A and B respectively , where AB = 15.4cm . The circles intersect at P and Q . Find PBQ in radians .

I did try it out . I joint PBQA to form a square which means that PBQ = 90 degrees = 1.57 radians .

However, the answer is 1.38 rad which means PBQ is not 90 degrees . Can I get a hint on where have I gone wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

$PBQA$ is not a square. If it were, you would have $AB=\sqrt2PB\approx 14.1$ cm, which is not.

Consider instead triangle $PBO$, where $O$ is the midpoint of $AB$. By the usual theorems on right triangles, you can easily find $\cos(\angle PBO)$.